# Restrict CL "Find" to Root Volume Only

Tags: unix, disk-volume

Because the default MacOS mount point for volumes is inside the root volume (i.e., `/Volumes/…`) `find / -iname "hidenseek"` searches every mounted volume, not just the root volume.

How can I restrict it to just the root volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-x` option will prevent `find` from descending into directories that have a different device number.

```
 find -x / ...expressions
```